# Trying to add a video into html but, the video won't load

Tags: html, video

```
<video controls autoplay src="uniform_shop.mp4" type="video/mp4"> . 
</video>
```

Im trying to the implement a video into my HTML code for a school assignment but, the area where the video should be comes up with a player but the video never loads.

The video is inside the same file as the pages so I don't knwo why it won't load.

Comment: When you put `Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.` in between your video tag does the text show?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nikhil, you should first check if the path is correct.
Secondly, you should check if the video format is supported. Currently, MP4, WebM and Ogg are supported only.(Though this should not be the case as you are using MP4 format with correct MIME type)
If you are using the supported video then check if you have used the right MIME type.
For fallback, you can try this syntax:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Any text between the `<video>` and `</video>` tags will be displayed in browsers that do not support the `<video>` element.
For more info on this, you can refer to [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).

Comment: If this answer help you then please mark it as accepted by clicking the check icon on question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the path of the video properly?

The syntax is right, I guess you are giving the wrong path to the `src` attribute.

Or you can try this also (If the path is right):

```
<video width="400" controls autoplay>
  <source src="uniform_shop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```